# I'm trying to add update information functionality, but instead of updating, it adds new record

Tags: php, laravel

So currently I'm trying to add the functionality to update user information, however, I'm not having much luck with it. Currently instead of updating the current user, my code creates a new record in the database. I have probably made a very simple mistake but I can't find it.

Settings view where the editing happens:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<form method="post" action="{{ route('updateProfile', $user) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('patch') }}

    <input type="text" name="first_name"  value="{{ $user->first_name }}" />

    <input type="text" name="last_name"  value="{{ $user->last_name }}" />

    <input type="text" name="username"  value="{{ $user->username }}" />

    <input type="email" name="email"  value="{{ $user->email }}" />

    <input type="password" name="password" />

    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" />

    <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

Patch route:

```
Route::patch('/profile/{username}/update', 'UsersController@updateProfile')->name('updateProfile');
```

UserController:

```
public function updateProfile(Request $request, User $user){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user->first_name = request('first_name');
        $user->last_name = request('last_name');
        $user->username = request('username');
        $user->email = request('email');
        $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));

        $user->save();

        return back();
    }
```

PagesController:

```
public function settings(){
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('settings', compact('user'));
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you try to fetch the user from the user model in the controller. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using model binding, changing your route `{username}` parameter to match `User` argument is all you need to do:

```
Route::patch('/profile/{user}/update', 'UsersController@updateProfile')->name('updateProfile')
```